# Speed up a MED function?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am trying to make a minimum edit distance function faster. Using numba `@jit` makes it surprisingly slower and not faster! It says for loops should be faster! `@njit` does not work. `xrange` and `range` seem to be slightly better than `ndindex`.

```
 #original: https://github.com/ferreirafabio/minimum-edit-distance-py
 #Calculate minimum edit distance, you can provide the cost of edit ops
 # @jit
 def med(tokens1, tokens2, subst=1, delete=1, insert=1):
    n,m = len(tokens1), len(tokens2)
    D = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in range(m):
    # for i,j in np.ndindex(D.shape) :  
            subst_cost = 0 if tokens1[i] == tokens2[j] else subst
            D[i,j] = min(D[i-1, j] + insert, D[i, j-1] + delete, D[i-1, j-1] + subst_cost)
    return D[n-1,m-1]
```

It may be possible to use some 2D operation because if you look at it, it is a NxM kernel. Here is an example on a 2x2 kernel:

```
| subst  | insert |
|--------|--------|
| delete |   x    |

| +1/0   |  +1    |
|--------|--------|
|    +1  |   min  |
```

Comment: What are the exact types of `tokens1` and `tokens2`? Are the length of array set to 2 in your benchmark? It seems very small for a use of numba. Please note that numba introduces an additional latency probably much bigger than the computation time of this 2x2 loop in CPython.

Comment: ~1000+ tokens. tokens can be string, list-of-int or list-of-strings

Comment: Can the string in the list-of-strings be bounded by a (quite small) size?

Comment: what do u mean by "bounded" ... btw the slowest part is that it has to loop over 1000x1000 array ...not the string comparison, cause the speed with ints is the ~same

Comment: By bounded, I mean that you can find a (small) integer `N` such as `max(map(len,tokens1))` and `max(map(len,tokens2))` are both always smaller than `N` (for all the calls you need). Is that true?

Comment: no.. but as far as i know string comparison by default check the len and the first character, before doing full comparison !

Answer (score 1):

Numba `@njit` does not work directly here since *list* of int/strings are apparently *unsupported yet*. As for `@jit`, numba could not work efficiently on such data structure as no direct memory accesses are possible.
However, numba can work very efficiently on numpy arrays containing native low-level types (eg. `np.int64`, but not python strings).

Here is the trick: we can convert the input lists to **numpy arrays**, then use a fast **vectorized numpy call** to compare the converted input arrays and finally use **numba** to efficiently compute the `D` values.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
@njit
def computeMedLine(D, subst_cost, i, delete, insert):
    for j in range(len(subst_cost)):
        D[i,j] = min(D[i-1, j] + insert, D[i, j-1] + delete, D[i-1, j-1] + subst_cost[j])

def fastMed(tokens1, tokens2, subst=1, delete=1, insert=1):
    npTok1 = np.array(tokens1, dtype=object)
    npTok2 = np.array(tokens2, dtype=object)

    n,m = len(tokens1), len(tokens2)
    D = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=np.uint32)
    for i in range(n):
        subst_cost = np.where(npTok1[i] == npTok2, 0, subst)
        computeMedLine(D, subst_cost, i, delete, insert)
    return D[n-1,m-1]
```

With input lists containing 1000 items, the code above is about *300 times faster* on my PC (without taking into account the JIT compilation time).